# Merging subarray objects with PHP

Tags: php, json

I can't for the life of me work out a nice way of getting an array of objects like this (would actually be a much larger array from a db):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Canterbury
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => West Coast
        )

)
```

Into a single level array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Canterbury
    [1] => West Coast
)
```

So that when I do a json_encode, it looks like this:

```
{"0":"Canterbury","1":"West Coast"}
```

Rather than this:

```
[{"name":"Canterbury"},{"name":"West Coast"}]
```

I've tried a variety of things, like using php's array combine and merge functions, but no luck.

Comment: `{"name":"Canterbury","name":"West Coast"}` --- it's not possible

Comment: `{"name":"Canterbury","name":"West Coast"}` defines an object with two `name` properties. Why would you want that?

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant - {"0":"Canterbury","1":"West Coast"} have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: You would get `["Canterbury", "West Coast"]`

Comment: The reason it looks like that originally, is that 'name' is the column in the db table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
$output = array();
foreach($objectArray as $oneObject)
    $output[] = $oneObject->name;
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Awesome this sorted it for me. My main issue was not realizing you could 'index into' the name property without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you just need to put the object's name attribute in place of the array's value:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $value = $value->name
}
```